# Logstash - Input from a web interface without conf file

Tags: logstash

Is logstash provide any web interface instead of conf file. I want to run the logstash without using conf file. But I want to enter the input of conf file from a UI/Web interface. Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible out of the box. What's the use case?

Comment: I have an input form is there there (web form) associated with an execute button. When i click on the execute button it need to create a configuration file (logstash configuration) according to my form input and execute it in logstash..... Its my requirement. Is there is any chance to done this use case using logstash?

Comment: Again, not possible out of the box but you can of course build your own web service tailored to this need.

Answer (score 1):

Commit your conf file to a git repo hosted in github or bitbucket. Check this repo out to your logstash installation conf.d directory and have a cron job check for commits and pull changes/restart logstash when a new commit is pulled. You could then edit your conf file in github.

Not hugely elegant but a possible solution